# draw ellipse relative to panel java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d, ellipse

Basically I want to draw an **ellipse** which its size is relative to **JPanel** in Java.

for example: `Ellipse2D e = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, w, h)`

Which **w** and **h** is the size of the panel. So by doing this, the **ellipse** will automatically resize when the panel is changing its size.

I have tried this but actually it doesn't work, I wrote this code for testing only.

```
public class Help extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String [] agrs){
        Help h = new Help();
        h.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        h.init();
    }

    public void init(){
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setSize(2000, 1000);

        JPanel a = new JPanel();
        a.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
        a.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow, 3));
        Help_Option k = new Help_Option(a.getPreferredSize().width/2, a.getPreferredSize().height/4);
        k.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 400));
        a.add(k);

        this.add(a);
        this.validate();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Help_Option extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener{
    private static int x, y;
    private Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, x, y);
    private Color c = Color.MAGENTA;    

    public Help_Option(int x, int y){
        Help_Option.x = x;
        Help_Option.y = y;
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.draw(ellipse);

        g2d.setColor(c);
        g2d.fill(ellipse);        

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g2d.drawString("Here I am", 250, 100);
    }

    public void setColor(Color c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if(ellipse.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())){
            setColor(Color.GREEN);
            repaint();
        }else{
            setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well x and y should be double, sorry I forgot to change but It doesn't work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your code snippet. In order to make it work, you need to initalize the ellipse in the Help_Option-Constructor otherwise it is draw at 0, 0 with the widht and height of 0 and 0.

```
...
private Ellipse2D ellipse = null; //also works w/o this assignment.
private Color c = Color.MAGENTA;    

public Help_Option(int x, int y){
    Help_Option.x = x;
    Help_Option.y = y;
    ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, x, y);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
...
```

If I change the code accordingly, the ellipse stays at its size even though I resize the window.

[image: Image with unscaled ellipse]

Please give me a hint (screenshot) what you mean.

Comment: I just got trolled! Why do I need to initialize the ellipse to null there? I tried exactly the same thing as you but not initialize null to the ellipse. But why that null make the code work?

Comment: The init with null is not necessary as variables of objects are null by default. I usually add this statement to make it clear - prob a stupid way of coding. Keep us posted if it also works w/o null on your end.

Comment: Do you mind upvote my answer when it fixed your issue?

Comment: OmGGGGG why it works now ??? I don't know how many times I pressed shift f6 with that code, it didn't work ... And now it works just fine ...

Comment: Sometime it's magic: If I tell the computers to behave, they immediately do it. - Joking apart, I guess there was some caching that gave you this weird behavior. Do you mind telling us the IDE and OS in your initial post?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to draw an ellipse which its size is relative to JPanel in Java.

Then you need to create the Ellipse object in the `paintComponent()` method. You can use the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods to get the current size of the panel.

Comment: I tried the solution below. It works! I did the same thing but not initialize the ellipse to null. I just don't understand why when I initialize the ellipse, it works ...